# django-websocket-redis redis connection using unix socket

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis

I'm using django-websocket-redis and have this in my settings.py:

```
WS4REDIS_CONNECTION = {
    'host': 'unix://var/run/redis/redis.sock',
    'db': 0,
    # 'port': 16379,
    # 'password': 'verysecret',
}
```

I tried all possible combinations of 'host' parameter and can't get it to connect using unix socket instead of tcp. I always get this message:

```
ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to /var/run/redis/redis.sock:6379. Name or service not known.
```

Is there a way to connect ws4redis from django to redis using unix socket? If there is, how?

Comment: have you tried ip (`127.0.0.1`) or host with single slash `unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock`. Alse veryfi that redis is listening on port `6379` or on socket in `/var/run/redis` directory

Comment: Try to make sure the redis is started and running. `ps aux | grep redis`

Comment: Yes. I tried all the combinations of naming the socket. And redis works through tcp and works using socket with other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you have to override default Redis connection settings of `ws4redis`

I've bumped into this when I was implementing custom Django command, which was supposed to send a websocket message on certain server-side events.

If you look at the source code of `RedisPublisher` class, you will notice this line at the very top:

`redis_connection_pool = ConnectionPool(**settings.WS4REDIS_CONNECTION)`

while comments for `ConnectionPool.__init__()` state following:

> By default, TCP connections are created connection_class is specified.
>   Use `redis.UnixDomainSocketConnection` for unix sockets.

So when you're instantiating `RedisPublisher` it uses `ConnectionPool` which, by default, does not know anything about sockets. Therefore 2 approaches are possible:

1. Switch default `Connection` to `UnixDomainSocketConnection` in `ConnectionPool` instantiation or
2. Substitute `ConnectionPool` with `StrictRedis` connection which has built-in capabilities to use unix socket (named argument `unix_socket_path`).

This is how I solved it using 2nd approach (it appears cleaner for me):

```
from redis import StrictRedis
from django.conf import settings
from ws4redis.publisher import RedisPublisher
from ws4redis.redis_store import RedisMessage

r = StrictRedis(**settings.WS4REDIS_CONNECTION)
publisher = RedisPublisher(facility='foobar', broadcast=True)
publisher._connection = r
msg = RedisMessage('ping')
publisher.publish_message(msg)
```

The whole magic is in `publisher._connection` line which ultimately switches connection, used by `RedisPublisher` class.
Since `_connection` assumes protected access, this looks like a bit dirty, but working solution.

You also need to specify following `WS4REDIS_CONNECTION` settings:

```
WS4REDIS_CONNECTION = {
    'unix_socket_path': '/tmp/redis.sock'
}
```

This is required for wsgi, since it appears to use built-in `redis.py` capability to connect to unix socket as it stated in [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis)

Comment: From the [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317081/redis-py-when-to-use-connection-pool) i'd say there's a confusion on when and how to use connection pools. In this case I'd say the option to use connection vs connection pool should be extracted to configuration.

Comment: There's a corresponding [issue](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis/issues/212) in Github

Comment: Actually [PR](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis/pull/213) with this feature was recently merged.